# XAMPP PHP - Send Mail

Tags: xampp

I wanna ask if my *xampp* version affects the sending of mail through xampp? I already configured *php.ini* and *sendmail.ini*

with
*smtp port = 587* or *465*
auth_password as my app password in my google account

It's not a problem now in the configuration now that this error already disappeared:

```
mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set()
```

What is the problem now?

Comment: Did you install any mailserver that listens on post 25 on your machine?

Comment: I'm new to this. Is it  I need to install phpmailer first with composer?

Comment: I am actually installing composer earlier and I got this:

"Some settings on your machine may cause stability issues with Composer.
If you encounter issues, try to change the following:

The Windows OneDrive folder is not supported on PHP versions below 7.2.23 and 7.3.10.
Upgrade your PHP (7.3.9) to use this location with Composer."

Should I upgrade my PHP now?

Comment: If you want to send mails, you either need to use a proper external mail server (then you would not use localhost as a mailserver) or you need to install one on your machine. If you want to use Google Mail, you need to configure that properly in your code. As you haven't shared any code, it's impossible to tell you what you did wrong